# Recursive function until counter is equal to 5 infinite loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

Hello I have an array with "hello" and an empty string "" inside it. The thing is that I want to be able to print 5 times the hello string inside the array but I'm running into an infinite loop. I set the random function and a counter because I don't always want to know what param I'll get but the result should be the same: print 5 times "hello".

This is my code:

```js
var a = ["hello", ""];
var randomValue = a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())];

function toresult(param){
  let counter= 1;

  if(param.length >=3 && counter <= 5){
      console.log(param)
      counter +=1

      //If I place the function here I would run into the infinite loop:  toresult(randomValue)

  } else{
      console.log("empty string PRINTED")
  }
}

toresult(randomValue)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an actual `for` loop?

Comment: Infinite loops occur because you don't provide an exit clause. Right now you redefine the counter variable every time the function is called. That is the part you need to resolve.You could solve this by initializing it if it is not passed to the function.

Comment: @scrappedcola u should just answer, that is correct answer, counter needs to be outside of the function.

Comment: OK @scrappedcola  post the answer so I can validate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinite loops occur because you don't provide an exit clause. Right now you redefine the counter variable every time the function is called. That is the part you need to resolve.You could solve this by initializing it if it is not passed to the function https://jsfiddle.net/rfbhk7de/.

```
var a = ["hello", ""];
var counter = 1;
var randomValue = a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())];

function toresult(param){ 

  if(param.length >=3 && counter <= 5){

  console.log("Yes, inside!!")
  counter +=1

  toresult(randomValue)

  }else{
  console.log("empty string PRINTED")

  }
}

toresult(randomValue)
```

An alternative option would be to also pass the counter variable in and use a default value for counter if none is passed in.

```
var a = ["hello", ""];
var randomValue = a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())];

function toresult(param, counter){ 
  counter = typeof(counter) !== "undefined" ? counter : 1; //fancy way of doing an if loop. Basically says if counter is defined then use the passed in counter else set to default 1
  if(param.length >=3 && counter <= 5){

  console.log("Yes, inside!!")
  counter +=1

  toresult(randomValue, counter)

  }else{
  console.log("empty string PRINTED")

  }
}

toresult(randomValue)
```

A jsfiddle of the second example: https://jsfiddle.net/yd1cxbvc/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that recursion is good for this matter. As far as i understand you want randomly do something but in a case of fundomiser return 1.  So it worth to try do while

```
var a = ["hello", ""];
var counter = 0;
do{
    randomValue = a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())]
    if(randomValue.length >=3){
        console.info(randomValue);
        counter++;
    }else{
       console.log("empty string PRINTED")
    }
}while( counter < 5)
```

Ok. Despite the fact you have an answer already. 
Here is solution based on a recursion.

```
var a = ["hello", ""];

function doPrint(counter){
    randomValue = a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())]
    if(!counter) return;
    if(randomValue.length >=3 && counter--){
        console.info(randomValue);

    }else{
       console.log("empty string PRINTED")
    }
    doPrint(counter);
}

doPrint(5);
```

Comment: Your code is also printing the inside the else condition...I don't want that

Comment: Can you edit the question with the requirements, Please. My code is replicating yours but not using recursion.

Comment: I need to use recursion, although may not be necessary in that particular case I need it for asynchronous purposes

Answer (score -1):

> **A recursive function** definition has one or more base cases, meaning
>   input(s) for which the function produces a result trivially (without
>   recurring), and one or more recursive cases, **meaning input(s) for
>   which the program recurs (calls itself)**.

You have to carefully pass the parameters into the same function call to termit as recursion, as shown below :

```
var a = ["hello", ""];

function toresult(count){
    if(count < 1) return;
    else {
        a.push('hello');
        return toresult(count-1);
    } 
}
toresult(5);


console.log(a); // ["hello", "", "hello","hello","hello","hello","hello"]
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete because you're removing the random empty string and I want to take that into account, not print it but take it into account as I posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, your requirement wasn't that clear to understand the whole purpose of your code. Also, the aim of this code is to provide a base for you to start with, and not a complete solution